add custom filter to plugins page?
I was wondering if it was possible to add a custom filter to the Wordpress backend plugins page (/wp-admin/plugins.php).  To ensure I'm being totally clear about what I'm referring to, I'm talking about the filters in the header underneath the page title that look similar to these options:
All (86) | Active (43) | Inactive (43) | Recently Active (1) | Drop-ins (3) | Auto-updates Enabled (51) | Auto-updates Disabled (35)
We have a bunch of custom plugins we've developed in-house that I think it would be handy if we could group using a new custom filter for this page.

you can do that with the help of 2 filters :
add_filter("plugins_list", function ($plugins) {
    
    $filter_code = "with_b";
    
    if (    isset($_GET["plugin_status"])
        &&  ($filter_code === $_GET["plugin_status"])
    ) {
        $GLOBALS["status"] = $filter_code; // setting the filter to display in current page
    }
    
    
    // preparation of the plugins in the special category
    $plugins[$filter_code] = array_filter($plugins["all"], function ($plugin) {
        return FALSE !== strpos($plugin["Name"], "b");
    });
    
    
    return $plugins;
    
});


// preparation of the link to the special category
add_filter("views_plugins", function ($views) {
    
    $filter_code = "with_b";
    
    $nb = $GLOBALS["totals"][$filter_code];
    $url = "plugins.php?plugin_status=$filter_code";
    
    $html  = "<a href=\"$url\"";
    if ( $GLOBALS["status"] === $filter_code ) {
        $html .= " class=\"current\" aria-current=\"page\"";
    }
    $html .= ">";
        $html .= "Name that contains \"b\"";
        $html .= "<span class=\"count\">($nb)</span>";
    $html .= "</a>";


    
    $views[$filter_code] = $html;
    
    
    return $views;
    
});

